# How can I remove straying Preboot folders in /Volumes?

Tags: hard-drive, high-sierra, apfs

When trying to eject a drive with Alfred, Preboot 93 showed up. I know they are APFS container volumes but when checking the `/Volumes` directory it shows that there are a lot of Preboot drives straying. Can these safely be deleted? Or is this how APFS works by creating more than one Preboot drive?

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Why don't you take a backup of them and then reboot your mac but you have way too many preboot folders on my mac I only have 4.

Comment: @Geek unsure if just copy pasting them provides a safe way to backup. I'd rather not break anything at system level by removing the folders with `rm` or moving them to the trash.